# SQL - bitwise AND all results of a boolean value field

Tags: sql, sql-server, bitwise-operators

I have a table that looks like this (just a single Boolean field):

```
| IsTrue      |
---------------
| 1           |
---------------
| 1           |
---------------
| 0           |
---------------
| 1           |
---------------
```

Is there a way I can do a Bitwise AND on all values in this field so that I have a single True/False result?

Something like: `select BITWISE_AND(IsTrue) from MyTable` which would have a result of just | 0 | ?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also be clear about whether the column is a *bit* or a *boolean*.  These are not necessarily the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a value that only takes on 0 or 1, then "bitwise and" is equivalent to `min()`:

```
select min(IsTrue) as "bitwise_and"
```

And "bitwise or" is equivalent to `max()`:

```
select max(IsTrue) as "bitwise_or"
```

This is a numerical fact, so it is independent of the database being used.

Comment: Great answer as usual @Gordon

Comment: I've found that you want to convert the bool to an int, but yep! This does the trick! much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most generic solution, if I can take at face value that the column contains either a `1` or a `0` as you've shown it above - is `min(IsTrue)`.

But a couple caveats:

You're asking for a "bitwise" `AND`, but you're *describing* a "logical" `AND` - which, if the column holds a numeric "1=TRUE or 0=FALSE", is the same; but in other cases may be only kinda-sorta the same.

Some databases provide bitwise operators, others don't.  And a bitwise aggregate function is something else entirely.  This is why `min` is a more general solution; it's a standard function that any database will provide.  And it will work in a wide range of circumstances, including the one you seem to be outlining.  It would fail if the column type is technically one over which your DBMS doesn't define `min` (or defines it in some weird way).  It would fail if a *negative* number could be interpreted as "true" (but in that case, maybe you could get by with `min(abs(isTrue))` or something like that).